# How can I change the migration order for an app to run after the other apps?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-serializer

I'm using ModelSerealizer to generate the 'api' of my project and I have a `casa = CasaLegislativa.objects.first ()` attribute as described in the code below:

```
Class SessaoPlenariaSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # ...

    casa = CasaLegislativa.objects.first ()

    # ...
```

When I run `python manage.py migrate` I get the following error:

```
Django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "base_casalegislativa" does not exist
```

This error occurs because the call to the `CasaLegislativa.objects.first ()` method of the SessionPlenariaSerializer class is called before the creation of the table for the CasaLegislativa class in the database.

The app 'api' has no Model and no migration (I can not use dependency on other migrations), but it is checked first because it comes first alphabetically. How can I change the order of the migration so that this app 'api' runs after the others?

Comment: I don't think it will help you solve the problem but you can specify what to migrate by calling the app name. so ./manage.py migrate YourAppName.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the migration order, all apps are loaded before migrations are even attempted. You just can't execute a query at this point. You need to move the query into a method or replace it with one that is lazily evaluated.

Comment: @kbnk I solved it this way. But seems a ugly hack.

Comment: @hansTheFranz, This may work (although my attempt failed), but I would need this automated task to be run by jobs (in travis, docker, for example)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to get the `casa` attribute and pass the `CasaLegislativa.objects.first()` call to a `get_casa` method. So the reference to the table will only be done at run time, solving the migration problems.
Not a good solution, but solved the problem.